# Algorithm to store complete binary tree into an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, binary-tree

I am learning data structure right now, from book I know that for a complete binary tree, we could store it in an array. But I cannot come up with an algorithm with it, nor could I transform an array into a complete binary tree. Can anyone help me with this in C? 
I think for a question like this could be solved in recursion, just like traversal in binary tree, but I cannot do it, nor could I solve it in non-recursion method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation

Comment: @PeteKirkham Thank you very much, you've give me a good direction, I know how to search for it now.:)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thank you:)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you, I would make for it. Could you please tell me why my question is not asked properly? I checked your page, but I cannot tell why it is not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a traversal In-Order function calling a pointer to function.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Peter Skarpetis, you can avoid using globals or `static`s passing an extra parameter after the pointer to function:

```
struct container {
    void *data;
    int count;
};

void tree_walk_recurse(const t_node *node, void (*func)(void *, void *), void *data)
{
    if (node->left) tree_walk_recurse(node->left, func, data);
    func(node->data, data);
    if (node->right) tree_walk_recurse(node->right, func, data);
}

void tree_walk(const t_node *root, void (*func)(void *, void), void *data)
{
    if (root && func) tree_walk_recurse(root, func, data);
}

void insert(void *data, void *ptr)
{
    struct data *array = ptr;

    array->data[array->count++] = data;
}

/* Traverse in-order using insert */
struct container array;

array.data = malloc(sizeof(struct data) * n);
array.count = 0;
tree_walk(root, insert, &array);
```

Comment: The function insert needs more parameters, maybe a pointer to the insertion position of the array so we can do a *ptr = data.

Comment: @AlterMann Thank you very much, but it seems I didn't expressed myself clearly. I think to store a complete binary into an array should not use in-order function, what i want, is store root in A[1], then big son in A[2], the little son  in A[3]. Then four grandsons in A[4], A[5], A[6], A[7]. Can you tell me how to store in this order?

Comment: @AlterMann Thanks again, I know it is same with heap storage, I know how to find a correct answer, thank you:)

Comment: @AlterMann ehhhh, it's not in-order, pre-order nor post-order. It's more like store data in line, one line at a time, so i think the key is to find out siblings, but I cannot come up with a good algorithm to solve this.